# Why do we add " ( ) => " before a function reference?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fluent-ui

I am learning typescript and was trying to implement a [detailList](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/detailslist) component from Microsoft Fluent UI, but I ran into some trouble:

```
Type '(ev: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>, checked: boolean) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>, checked?: boolean | undefined) => void'.
```

In the code there was a function called _onChangeCompactMode being referenced when a toggle button is clicked

```
  private _onChangeCompactMode = (ev: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>, checked: boolean): void => {
this.setState({ isCompactMode: checked });
```

Here is where it's referenced:

```
  <Fabric>
    <div className={classNames.controlWrapper}>
      <Toggle
        label="Enable compact mode"
        checked={isCompactMode}
        onChange={this._onChangeCompactMode}
        onText="Compact"
        offText="Normal"
        styles={controlStyles}
      />
       ...
  </Fabric>
```

I fixed this issue by changing this line `onChange={this._onChangeCompactMode}` to this `onChange={() => this._onChangeCompactMode}`

I am not sure why this made it work. My understanding is, I passed a function reference. But why wouldn't it work as it is without `() =>`

Still new here, so constructive feedback is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because the types don't match. Have a look at the [toggle documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/toggle)

`onChange` has the type:

```js
(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>, checked?: boolean) => void
```

Note that the `checked` is optional, but in your implementation it's not. It should work if you make it optional:

```js
private _onChangeCompactMode = (ev: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>, checked?: boolean): void => {
this.setState({ isCompactMode: checked ?? false });
```

Make sure to add a default now that checked is optional, like I did with `checked ?? false`

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful about the meaning of `this` in JSX callbacks. If you forget to bind `this._onChangeCompactModeand` pass it to onChange, this will be undefined when the function is actually called. That's why you have to use the `arrow function`, like you did. Or the `_onChangeCompactMode` itself has to be an arrow function, like so:

```
  _onChangeCompactMode = () => {
    // your code
  }
```

then pass its reference:

```
onChange={this._onChangeCompactMode}
```

They should work the same